# I want to display time as 09032014124008 rather than 9/3/2014 12:40:08 AM

Tags: datetime, format

I want to display time as 09032014124008 rather than 9/3/2014 12:40:08 AM
When I use DateTime.Now, the format is the latter one.
Kindly suggest how can I get it in the required format.

Comment: What language or system?

Comment: Since you haven't listed any languages/environments, I'll suggest you print out your date on a piece of paper, use some scissors to cut up the printout into individuals chunks, then use some glue to attach the bits to a new piece of paper in the order you'd like them to be in.

Comment: Use FormatDateTime(), or whatever it might be called on your OS/language.  Failing that, parse the thing you have with string functions or regex or whatever you have in your OS/language.  OH - scissors and glue aparrently also work but I didn't think of that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify a custom format string on the call to .ToString()

For your example you would use:

```
        DateTime.Now.ToString("MMddyyyyhhmmss")
```

Also see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx) for additional format string options